# Display youtube video inline on IOS devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, youtube

I am trying to build a small web app which requires playing a youtube video behind some text.

I tried using the youtube Iframe api 'playsinline' parameter, but it won't work and display videos in fullscreen on IPhones.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

---

### UPDATE

Since IOS 10 came out html5 video tag inline attribute is supported on safari and youtube videos can be played inline,
and thus @David Anderton answer is marked correct.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH11-DontLinkElementID_12

Hope it helps

Comment: actually FWIW when doing it with uiwebview i set mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction to YES and that stopped it auto launching.  perhaps you have something similar available in your html version

Comment: Ok, but where is the code that you have tried so far

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `playsinline=1` paramerer to the embed url. Add `?` or `&` before as appropriate; `?` if the only paramerter, `&` to concatenate with other params.

Example:

```
<iframe
  src="https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?playsinline=1">
</iframe>
```

From [YouTube iFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters):

> This parameter controls whether videos play inline or fullscreen in an HTML5 player on iOS. Valid values are:
>   0: This value causes fullscreen playback. This is currently the default value, though the default is subject to change.
>   1: This value causes inline playback for UIWebViews created with the allowsInlineMediaPlayback property set to TRUE.

Comment: I have found that this also works directly on a video tag and that it works with any string value that does not evaluate to a boolean, such as true  `<video
              playsinline="playinline" ..../>`

Answer (score 3):

You can't play videos inline in the browser on iOS. If its a hybrid app(that is using a webview), then while instantiating the webview you can set the allowsInlineMediaPlayback and the video tag in the HTML should have the "webkit-playsinline" attribute.

Comment: No way of doing so in a pure web app?

Comment: You can add "webkit-playsinline" attribute to the video tag. It will play inline on iPad, but not iPhones. No way to play video inline in the browser on iPhones.

Comment: It's already possible on iPhones, as long as the iframe has the `webkit-playsinline` attribute. The `src` should also have the parameter `enablejsapi=1`, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples). If you're using a WebView, also set `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` to `true`.

Comment: This comment is no longer accurate as of iOS 10; see the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40961655/303896

Answer (score 1):

First set `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` and `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` to true.

Then check your iFrame HTML:

```
<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='640' height='480' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/5_ofy9Ae87M?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>
```

Note `playsinline=1` and `autoplay=1` in the HTML.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry if I wasn't clear but I am not using webview.
it's not a native app.

maybe you have a workaround?