# How do you prevent an embedded YouTube video from going fullscreen in iOS Safari or Chrome?

Tags: ios, youtube, embed, fullscreen

I have the following markup:

```
<iframe allowfullscreeen="0" frameborder="0" height="360" id="ytplayer" type="text/html" webkitallowfullscreen="0" width="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qIuK3JZ33uk"></iframe>
```

When I hit the play button on iOS Safari or Chrome, the video enters a fullscreen player. It can be minimized back to its in-page size by clicking the icon in the bottom right, but is going fullscreen at first preventable?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is the answer [Display youtube video inline on IOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367473/display-youtube-video-inline-on-ios-devices)

```
playsinline=1
```

in the src url.