# Prevent webkit view from allowing videos going fullscreen automatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

(iPhone, iOS 11.4) I'm loading a website into a WebKit view (https://www.utep.edu/liberalarts/music/) but the page has a carousel(?) of photos and one video that allows the video to go fullscreen each time the video comes around in the carousel. Can I prevent this from happening automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks to Shreyas ([Display youtube video inline on IOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367473/display-youtube-video-inline-on-ios-devices/40961655#40961655)) for leading me to the answer)

After I selected the WebKit view in Interface Builder there was an option in the attributes inspector called "Inline Playback" that needed to be checked. That was it!

Comment: That should correspond to the `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` boolean, docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1614793-allowsinlinemediaplayback)